# SQL query with multiple groupings - Group machines by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling with a report i have been asked to compile using SQL Server 2012.

The report needs to consist of the number of machines built within a month displayed in a bar chart. We have 3 different makes of machines. The query i am trying to write should display machines B,Q,W and the total of those machines built for January, February etc.

The below query groups the machines into the relevant names and gives a count (also only includes the model of machine required )

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1) AS Workstations, 
       COUNT(*) AS Count, 
       Model00 AS "Machine Model"
FROM Computer_System_DATA
WHERE (Model00 LIKE N'HP Compaq Elite 8300 USDT')
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1), Model00
HAVING (SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1) LIKE 'W%') OR
       (SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1) LIKE 'B%') OR
       (SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1) LIKE 'Q%') OR
       (SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1) LIKE 'Y%') OR
       (SUBSTRING(Name00, 1, 1) = 'AND HP Compaq Elite 8300 USDT')
```

I also have another query which uses the same table and displays the Month and the total of machine built in that month -

```
SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(02), TimeKey, 101) AS Month, 
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Computer_System_DATA
GROUP BY CONVERT(Varchar(02), TimeKey, 101)
ORDER BY Month
```

My question is, is there a way to combine the two query's to give me the total amount of B, Q and W machines built within each month.

My apologies if this isn't clear or if I have missed anything. If anything is needed to help then please let me know. I'm new to SQL and this forum, I'm struggling to understand the concept of having multiple groups.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can also simplify your logic:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(02), TimeKey, 101) AS Month, 
       COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Computer_System_DATA
WHERE Name00 like 'W%' OR
      Name00 like 'B%' OR
      Name00 like 'Q%'
GROUP BY CONVERT(Varchar(02), TimeKey, 101)
ORDER BY Month;
```

You do not need to use `like` and `substring` for the comparison.

To get the totals separately:

```
SELECT CONVERT(Varchar(02), TimeKey, 101) AS Month, 
       COUNT(*) AS Total,
       sum(case when Name00 like 'W%' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_W,
       sum(case when Name00 like 'B%' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_B,
       sum(case when Name00 like 'Q%' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_Q
FROM Computer_System_DATA
WHERE Name00 like 'W%' OR
      Name00 like 'B%' OR
      Name00 like 'Q%'
GROUP BY CONVERT(Varchar(02), TimeKey, 101)
ORDER BY Month;
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response Gordon, the query was exactly what I needed. And in seeing what you have done this has helped me understand the logic behind it.